# How to create a custom GtkHScale slider?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, glade

I'm currently designing a GUI to display images on screen using Python 2.6, Glade-3 and GTK. It uses 2 sliders (2 x GtkHScale) in order to "clip" the image of any bright/dark areas. (like below)

upper clip ----------------|====

lower clip ===|-----------------

I think that it would look much neater if the two sliders were combined onto one GtkHScale giving the "blue line" between the 2 sliders in order to show which bits of the image are being clipped. (much like the mock up below)

Clipping -----|============|----

I'm using Glade-3 to create the slider but i think this customisation will have to be included in the Python code and not the Glade file? Any ideas on how to create a custom GtkHScale?